# Trouble ussing Buddy to test a project using Django REST FRAMEWORK POSTGRE AS DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jenkins, buddy.com

Hello I'm currently trying to implement **Buddy** with my little StartUp that is using **DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK** as a base. I found a very good example on the site. Unfortunately in the exmaple the used a MySql DB and I'm using Postgre as DB. My **settings.py** is:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'DBname',
    'USER': 'DBuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'DBpassword',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
}
```

My **Buddy** execute look somethig like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
cd Project
python manage.py test
```

I also created postgre service in **Buddy**
like version: latest, Hostname: postgres, Port:5432, Login:DBuser, Password:DBpassword, Name of a database to be created on container startup: DBname
When I run the build Test of my project an error message apears like this:

```
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Action failed: see logs above for details
```

I really don't now how to fix this, it appears that Buddy creates the database correctly but for some reason django does not reconise that it exists.

Pd: The proyect works fine on my laptop and my friends. I'ts only when I tried to run it on buddy where it gives me problems

Comment: You need to set the `HOST` key in your database settings, you said it was "postgres"?

Comment: If you are using localhost postgres then set HOST:'localhost' or you are using remote postgres then set that PC host or domain name

Comment: Hi, I did review the chagenes you suggest and implemented them on **settiings.py** however it did not help me for running **Buddy**.
```could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Action failed: see logs above for details```
at least it gave me a new error

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I did tried change the name of the ```HOSTNAME``` However Buddy doesn't allow the ``HOSTNAME```  to be 'localhost' so I'm kind on scuare one